# How does this piece of Javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

I understand that T is an object of Twit and that objects can be made from classes. But from this declaration it looks like T is being made from a variable and not a class. Can someone clarify please?

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...',
    consumer_secret:      '...',
    access_token:         '...',
    access_token_secret:  '...'
})
```

Comment: Classes in JavaScript are *first-class*, they can be bound to variable names (more technically they can be *expressions* instead of *statements*).

Comment: In what way does it look like what you say it looks like?

Comment: Keep in mind in JS there is no such thing as a "class" in the traditional OOP sense, you have functions, and functions can be assigned to variables.

Comment: @dman2306 untrue as of ES 6, there are properties of ES 6 classes not shared by conventional constructor functions.

Comment: @Jared Smith Do you have any examples or links about this? I've always thought that the ES6 class syntax is just syntactical sugar for our standard prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @Shilly how would you subclass `Function` or `Array` using standard prototypal inheritance? Additional differences: class declarations are not hoisted like function declarations, classes throw when not called with `new`, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I would just use an object wrapper myArray with the array as a property so I can 'extend' array in the myArray prototype without actually touching the base prototype. Concerning the hoisting, we don't actually hoist, we declare everything at the top of its scope. Anyways, I 'm missing the point I guess why dmans comment is not true.

Comment: @JaredSmith Fair enough, however, if I'm not mistaken, ES6 classes are really just a convenience. At the end of the day, JS is, and always will be a prototypal language. Also the question wasn't tagged as ES6.

Comment: @Shilly dmans comment is entirely true. If you declare `class Foo` you can still access `Foo.prototype`, and indeed it is frequently still necessary to do so. My comment is also true: it is possible to do things with ES 6 classes that you cannot do with bare functions. Not really an either/or kind of situation. Note that your wrapper idea won't work for subclassing `Function` like it does for `Array`.

Comment: @dman2306 yup. See my response to Shilly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function`s in JavaScript are first class objects and can be assigned to variables like anything else.

Comment: Okay thanks! Coming from C++/JAVA it looked really strange to me. So good to know you can store functions in as variables.

Answer (score 0):

example to add to other answers:

```js
var Twit = function(){
  console.log("hello");
}

t = new Twit;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @DanielAWhite's accurate answer, consider the following C code:

```
int i;
if (x == y)
{
  i = 3;
}
else
{
  i = 5;
}
```

versus

```
int i = x == y ? 3 : 5;
```

In C++ for example, when you declare a class its similar to the `if` above: its a statement. It cannot be bound to a variable. "Classes" in JavaScript are more like the ternary *expression*, they can be assigned to an arbitrary name (i.e. be a valid RValue for an assignment).

```
// valid ES 6 code

class Foo {
  constructor: function() {...}
}

var foo = new Foo();

// also valid and more-or-less equivalent:

var Foo = class {
  constructor: function() {...}
};

var foo = new Foo();
```

Answer (score -5):

**Test.js file  on node js**

```
    var Test={
             testJson:function(){
                            return [
                                     {
                                      'nome'    :'Name'
                                     }
                               ]
                }
            }
module.exports=Test;
```

**Another File**

```
const {testJson} = require('Test.js'); //initialize

testJson();
```

//call variable like function

Comment: can you clarify this?

Comment: a variable can have access to direct function and can be called as a direct function on nod js you can declare a constant variable at the same name used on the file you called with the require on my example const {testJson}